# How to properly update the ObservableCollection from another thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.5

If I use an `ActionBlock` for a database call, and need to update the GUI (perhaps an `ObservableCollection`).  Is looping through the result set and using the `Dispatcher.BeingInvoke` a good solution, or is there a better way?

I wanted to load in one row at a time to the GUI, since even with virtualization enabled it seemed like if I updated the entire observable collection at once the GUI would hang till it could render the whole datagrid.

Some sample code which simulates the situation:

```
ActionBlock<Func<Task>> _block = new ActionBlock<Func<Task>>(action => action());

        _block.Post(async () =>
            {
                await Task.Delay(1000); // Perhaps Long database read

                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) // Perhaps looping over database result set
                {
                    await Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( // Need to update GUI
                        new Action(
                            () =>
                            {
                                // Add new object to collection (GUI will update DataGrid one row at a time).
                                MyModel.MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() { MyInt = i });
                            }
                        ), DispatcherPriority.Background
                    );
                }
            });
```

Comment: You have to get back on the UI thread.  You can run an update every X records.  Simply cache them as they are read until you hit X, then pull them from your cache, pass them to your Action, and throw it on the Dispatcher.  Blam.

Answer (score 1):

If you add call Dispather.BeginInvoke inside loop, then you update you UI 100k times. Ideally I would to this:

```
//do as much work as possible in background thread
var items = new MyClass[100000];
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
   items[i] = new MyClass{ MyInt = i;}
}
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => //update UI just once
   MyModel.MyCollection = new ObservableCollection(items);
));
```

if your virtualization really works, it should be no problem.

in order to avoid adding large number in UI thread, you could split it to smaller portions of data:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   await Dispatcher.BeginInvokenew Action(() =>
   {
      for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++) { //add thousand items at once
         MyModel.MyCollection.Add(items[i * 1000 + j])
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is looping through the result set and using the Dispatcher.BeingInvoke a good solution, or is there a better way?

There's never a good reason to use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` in a modern application.

In your case, since you're already using TPL Dataflow, you can just change your `ActionBlock` to a `TransformManyBlock`, and link it to a separate `ActionBlock` that executes on the UI thread. Something like:

```
var _getRowsBlock = new TransformManyBlock<Func<Task<IEnumerable<TRow>>>, TRow>(
    action => action());
var _updateUiBlock = new ActionBlock<TRow>(row =>
{
  MyModel.MyCollection.Add(new MyClass() { MyInt = i });
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
  TaskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext(),
});
_getRowsBlock.LinkTo(_updateUiBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

_block.Post(async () =>
{
  await Task.Delay(1000); // Perhaps Long database read

  return result.Rows; // return the database result set
});
```

> I wanted to load in one row at a time to the GUI, since even with virtualization enabled it seemed like if I updated the entire observable collection at once the GUI would hang till it could render the whole datagrid.

Well, then you're probably looking at the wrong solution. I don't see how adding data one row at a time would help. If the UI is hammered adding 1000000 rows at once, then adding 1000000 rows one at a time would hammer it even more...

You may have to consider a solution where you *don't* load 1000000 rows into your UI.

Comment: 1000000 rows was an exaggeration to highlight the slow load, but even so with a modest amount of rows and columns it seems like the WPF window hangs for a second or two before it can fully refresh the DataGrid.  Is that just always the expected behavior?

Comment: @user17753: If you are only loading the rows that are displayed, then WPF should be pretty much instantaneous. If you're loading hundreds or thousands of rows the user can't even see, then yes, of course it will be slower.